# Найти массив в котором есть определённое поле с определённым ключом

Tags: php

Есть json-строка с множеством данным, которую я декодировал в множество массивов при помощи json_decode. В каждом массиве есть поле **name**. Например `["name"]=> string(5) "Seoul"`. Как мне искать именно поле "name" именно с ключом Seoul? И если перед этим полем есть поле `["code"]=> string(3) "SEL"`, как мне запарсить его?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, 'Seoul' - это не ключ, а значение. Ключи в данном случае - это 'name', 'code'. Обращаться к значению по ключу можно следующим образом: `$array['name']`. Как найти массив с определенным значением ключа name? Пройтись циклом по всем, проверить значение каждого.

Выражение "перед этим полем" тоже не особо корректно. Все ключи массива равноправны, хотя php и поддерживает исходный порядок. Так что, просто взять и обратиться к значению элемента массива по ключу code.

Comment: Сначала идёт ключ "code", а после него идёт ключ "name". Мне нужно найти, в каком массиве расположено значение "Seoul", а затем, запарсить из этого же массива значение ключа "code".

Comment: Они только в тексте идут "сначала" и "после". В паспаршенном массиве они равноправны. У вас уже есть готовый массив, вам его не надо снова "парсить". Найдите массив с нужным значением name в цикле и возьмите из него code. Код за вас я писать не буду - попытайтесь сделать это самостоятельно, иначе никогда не сможете выучить язык.

Comment: Написал код. Можете гордиться мной :)

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл на просторах StackOverfow замечательную функцию поиска номера многомерного массива(или как это правильно называется?):

```
function searcharray($value, $key, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
       if ($val[$key] == $value) {
           return $k;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

При помощи этой функции вытащил номер массива и уже располагая номером массива изъял из него значение ключа **code**:

```
$cities_json = file_get_contents('json/cities.json');
$data = json_decode($cities_json, true);
$key = searcharray($geo['city']['name_en'], 'name', $data);
$origin = $data[$key]['code']; // IEV
```